# Change text in legend base r

Tags: r

I want to change the text in the legend, I have not come around how to do that. For exampe change A and B to D and C. Any suggestions?

```
A <- c(10,5,5)
B <- c(30,10,10)

df <- cbind(A,B)

df <- t(df)

as.matrix(df)

barplot(df, beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

Comment: This:  `barplot(df, beside = TRUE, legend = TRUE, legend.text = c('D', 'C'))`?

Comment: I don't know why you are learning the base plotting system and you might have a good reason. However, after spending time learning both, I strongly recommend focusing on `ggplot2` as it is by far superior imo. Look here: https://ggplot2-book.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply supply a vector with the legend text (one for each color) to the argument `legend.text`:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df), beside = TRUE, legend.text = c("C", "D", "E"))
```

[image]

If you want to style the legend any further you need to put arguments inside a named list and pass it to the `args.legend` argument (look at `?legend`) for further arguments.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(10,5,5),
                 B = c(30,10,10))

barplot(as.matrix(df), beside = TRUE, legend.text = c("C", "D", "E"), args.legend = list(x = "bottomright"))
```

[image]